# EJS, node js forEach loop on include

Tags: node.js, loops, foreach, include, ejs

When using this syntax to loop on a 'component' EJS is complaining that task is not an object but if replaced with task._id it's fine.

Any ideas please?

```
  <? tasks.forEach( function( task ){ ?>
      <?- include('_task'); ?>
  <? }) ?>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you replacing `task` with `task._id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to pass `task` to your `include` then it'd be something like this:

```
<? tasks.forEach(function(task) { ?>
    <?- include('_task', {task: task}) ?>
<? }) ?>
```

Top-level data is automatically included but local variables need to be passed explicitly. See https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes

Comment: That's exactly what I needed :) Thanks @skirtle ... I assumed it would have access to the objects just as 'tasks' but it's not the case.

Comment: @Kris When you do an `include` it gets rendered as a totally separate template, so it can't see anything from the surrounding template. By default it just gets passed the same `locals` object as the original template. EJS doesn't even know that your `task` variable exists, code inside your `<? ?>` blocks just gets compiled directly into the template function without any understanding by EJS.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks once again :)

Comment: maybe I'm late for the party, but the only way I found to get a `foreach` work with `include` template is by using `<% include _task %>` as written [here](https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes)